# Isn't there any other way to get Reputation?

Tags: support, reputation

Well, I have gone through the Tour and I'm aware of earning reputation. I have pretty much reputation in stack overflow so that I can comment and post answers and do other basic things.

But, I'm pretty new at Programmers, and I keep monitoring this site for architectural knowledge. Many times I come across some questions, where I really can't post an answer but can comment. But I lack the reputation to comment here.

Any help would be great. :)

Comment: See also: [Help Center: What's reputation? How do I earn it?](https://programmers.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). Asking good questions and writing good answers are the primary ways to get rep, but suggesting good edits will also give you a small +2 if they get accepted.

Comment: You are 3 points away from being able to comment everywhere on Programmers. That's a single question upvote, or two _good_ edits. Also, you are 124 points away from reaching 200 points on Stack Overflow, and earning yourself the [association bonus](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/07/cross-site-account-associations/) that will allow you to comment on every SE site.

Comment: see [How does a lurker gain reputation to receive the privilege for commenting?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/164035/165773)

Comment: @Yannis - `association bonus` is only [*indirectly* retroactive](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/73810/213957)

Comment: Thanks guys. I now have got enough reputation to comment. :)